# Get the value of nested radio button group in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get the value of each selected radio button from each group which follows in a row.

```
<button ion-button (click)="sample()">Test</button>
    <ion-list *ngFor="let item of test; let i = index">
        <ion-item text-wrap  padding no-lines>
          <h2>{{i + 1}}. {{item.Ask}}</h2>
        </ion-item>
        <form [formGroup]="regis_form">
            <ion-list radio-group formControlName="uanswer"  [(ngModel)]="test['uanswer'+i]">
        <ion-item >
            <ion-label>A. {{item.Alt_Ans_1}}</ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="A" name="uanswer"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-label>B. {{item.Alt_Ans_2}}</ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="B" name="uanswer"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>

           <ion-label>C. {{item.Alt_Ans_1}}</ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="C" name="uanswer"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>


          </form>

        </ion-list>
```

Example

```
1.Question 1
A. Ant
B. Bat
C. Cat

Question 2
A.Dog
B.Eagle
C.Donkey
```

JS

```
sample(){
  console.log(this.uanswer)
}
```

How do i get the value of each selected radio from the list into the console.

Answer (score 0):

For passing the form-controls from parent to child- then have look at this blog, this might help you out - http://brophy.org/post/nested-reactive-forms-in-angular2/

Refer the below answer if you do not have nested children.

```
//import necessary modules
import {FormArray,FormBuilder,FormControl} from '@angular/forms'
```

In your constructor inject form builder

```
...
regis_form:any;
test:Array<any>;
constructor(private _fb:FormBuilder){}

//then initialize the form builder
ngOnInit(){
    this.regis_form = this._fb.group({
        radioGroup:this._fb.array([
          //assuming this.test has already been initialized
          this.addRadioGroup(this.test);
      ])
    });
}

//add your group 
addRadioGroup(test){
    let radioGroupControl = <FormArray>this.regis_form.controls.radioGroup;
    for(let i=0;i<test.length;i++){
        radioGroupControl.push(this.radioAnswerForm(test[i]));
    }
}

//initialize each value 
radioAnswerForm(valueFromArray){
    return this._fb.group({
        uanswer:[valueFromArray],
        ask:[valueFromArray.Ask],
        alt_ans_1:[valueFromArray.Alt_Ans_1],
        alt_ans_2:[valueFromArray.Alt_Ans_2],
       alt_ans_3:[valueFromArray.Alt_Ans_3],
   });
}

sample(){
    // now iterate through form control to get the value 
}
```

I have changed the form considering that there are no child components

```
<button ion-button (click)="sample()">Test</button>
<form [formGroup]="regis_form">
    <div formArrayName = "radioGroup">
        <div *ngFor="let radio of regis_form.controls.radioGroup.controls; 
        let i = index">
        <div text-wrap  padding no-lines>
          <h2>{{i + 1}}. radio.get('ask').value</h2>
        </div>


        <div>
            <label>A. {{radio.get('alt_ans_1').value}}</label>
            <input type="radio"  [value]="regis_form.controls.radioGroup.controls[i].controls.alt_ans_1">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>B. {{radio.get('alt_ans_2').value}}</label>
            <input type="radio"  [value]="regis_form.controls.radioGroup.controls[i].controls.alt_ans_2">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>C. {{radio.get('alt_ans_1').value}}</label>
            <input type="radio"  [value]="regis_form.controls.radioGroup.controls[i].controls.alt_ans_3">
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Hope this helps